# Why does ThreadMXBean.getThreadCpuTime return the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading

I try to use `ThreadMXBean.getThreadCpuTime` to get the CPU time of main thread. However, I get the the same time although the thread must have done some work which needs time. Now, I doubt the accurancy of using `ThreadMXBean.getThreadCpuTime` to get the CPU time. My example code is below,

```
package edu.seu.juc.problem;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class TestGetThreadCpuTime {
    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    /***
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("CPU time: " + ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCpuTime(Thread.currentThread().getId())
                / (1000 * 1000));

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            lock.lock();


            Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Integer sum = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
                sum += j;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);


            System.out.println("total: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
            System.out.println("CPU time: " + ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCpuTime(Thread.currentThread().getId())
                    / (1000 * 1000));

            System.out.println("blocked time: " + ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadInfo(Thread.currentThread().getId()).getBlockedTime());
            System.out.println("waited time: " + ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadInfo(Thread.currentThread().getId()).getWaitedTime());

            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Result is below

```
CPU time: 140
1783293665
total: 220
CPU time: 140
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 217
CPU time: 156
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 210
CPU time: 171
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 215
CPU time: 187
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 204
CPU time: 187
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 203
CPU time: 187
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 203
CPU time: 187
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
```

Why does the CPU time keeps `187ms`? It seems it is not reasonable.

Comment: this is the main thread, why do you think the time is wired?

Comment: I have a loop in the main thread. I think each loop will waste some cpu time, in other word, the cpu time will increase. Like, the first is 140ms, then 156ms, then 171ms. But when increased to 187ms, the time stays the same! I doubt that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time you see its based on your computer's OS behaviour, how the OS performs the task. 187ms you see it now, but if you restart your computer or run this code in another time then you will not see consistent 187ms time. 
I ran you code and this is the result:

```
  main CPU time: 143
 1783293665
 total: 230
 main CPU time: 169
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 235
main CPU time: 195
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 215
main CPU time: 208
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 218
main CPU time: 220
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 207
main CPU time: 225
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 209
main CPU time: 231
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 209
main CPU time: 238
blocked time: -1
waited time: -1
1783293665
total: 215
main CPU time: 247
blocked time: -1
  waited time: -1
```

Comment: Could you help me increase the loop number to see whether the CPU time will stay the same.

Comment: Its not same as I explained, I changed loop count to 20, and last 10 times are: 265, 270, 274, 279, 284, 290, 294, 298, 302, 307

Comment: Thank you for your test. This may depend on the machine.